# Count total search objects count in template using django-haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, xapian

I am using django haystack with xapian as the backend search engine. I am using `FacetedSearchView` and `FacetedSearchForm` for faceting over the search. I have passed `searchqueryset` to the `FacetSearchView` in my `urls.py` file.

But the problem is I cannot access that `searchqueryset` in template. All I want to do is count the number of objects in `searchqueryset` found.

In shell I could achieve it using S`earchQuerySet().filter(content="foo").count()`, how can I do that similarly in the template? Please guide. I want the total number of objects matching the search.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Haystack uses the standard django pagination: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Showing `{{ page.object_list|length }}` of `{{ page.paginator.count }}` Results on Page `{{ page.number }}` of `{{ page.paginator.num_pages }}`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show the result range instead of page number, e.g. **"Results 21-40 of 1001"**, You can do

```
Results {{ page.start_index }} - {{ page.end_index }} of {{ page.paginator.count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ page.object_list | length }}
```

Comment: this only tells you how many objects are on this page of results. It doesn't tell you how many results were returned in total (ex: Showing 20 of 53 - Showing {{ page.object_list | length }} of {{ HOW DO YOU GET THIS NUMBER OVER HERE}})