# How to get the count of search results in haystack search?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack for searching. How can i display in the template the count of search results found using haystack search in database? I mean where do i have to change my haystack views to get the count of searchquery. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: I think you can find a better answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261462/count-total-search-objects-count-in-template-using-django-haystack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `SearchQuerySet.count()`? In the template, it would be `{{ mysearchqueryset.count }}`

http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#count

Comment: in my haystack urls i have done qs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-created').count()
and in my template i am using {{ query.count}} but it is giving some kind of Attribute error :  

'int' object has no attribute 'auto_query'
please help.

Comment: Naturally, if you call `count()` once, you no longer have a `searchqueryset` but an `int`. Remove the `count` call from your view. If you pass your view that `qs = SearchQuerySet().auto_query('my_query_here')`, then in your template type `{{ qs.count }}` you'll get your count.

Comment: i got it. had to define my on function count in form.py in haystack. Thank you for help.